# Removing files of a specific extension unix

Tags: unix, freebsd

Quick question, how do I  recursively remove files of a specific extension? I wish to remove all .svn folders from a project.

```
rm -Rf www/ "*.svn"
```

The above seems to remove everything. Im using FreeBSD.

Thanks

Comment: You write "remove files of a specific extension", but that's *not* what you want to do.  What you want to do (and what most of the answers have been about) is how to remove all directories named *exactly* "`.svn`" and their contents.  So please clarify your question.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that you are happy with the list first.

```
find www -name '.svn' -type d -ls
```

Restrict to directories. SVN always names them `.svn`.

```
find www -depth -name '.svn' -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: the OP asked for **"files of a specific extension"**, not (only) directories.

Comment: I think the OP might be confused. They also said "I wish to remove all .svn folders from a project". Given that scope I think that anything like `-iname '*.svn'` is asking for trouble.

Comment: You can add -depth at the start of the command line and you won't get the errors. You might also be able to use -delete rather than -exec, but I don't know how it will behave with directories.

Comment: `-delete` doesn't play well with directories. Good call on `-depth`.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the xargs command, i find it more intuitive, so:

```
find www -name '.svn' -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r
```

if you want to remove .svn folders, if you are interested in deleting files:

```
find www -name '.svn' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

or you can remove everything:

```
find www -name '.svn' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r
```

if you want to be sure of what you will delete, launch the find command without the xargs :-)

good luck!

Comment: You really want to use find .... -print0 | xargs -0 ... if you're going to do this, otherwise spaces may cause you problems.

Answer (score 0):

chdir to the the working directory and run:

```
find . -iname '.svn' -exec rm -fr {} \;
```

OR you can specify the path directory like this:

```
find path -iname '.svn' -exec rm -fr {} \;
```

Comment: the OP asked for "files of a specific extension", not (only) directories.

Answer (score 0):

By typing :

`rm -Rf www/ "*.svn"`

You ask to remove the www folder and every *.svn files.

What you certainly want is to remove every *.svn inside the www folder, so you should use:

`rm -Rf www/*.svn`

(without the space)

Comment: This doesn't work recursively. Presumably the www directory has other directories which also contain a .svn directory.

Answer (score -1):

not sure if this is the best way to get rid of a repository, but this should do what you need:

`find www -name "*.svn" -exec rm -rfv {} \;`

**Update:** here is a [nice description](http://www.compuspec.net/reference/os/freebsd/find/find_and_execute_with_pipe.shtml) of BSD's `find`.

Comment: this would remove also foo.svn, which is not the wanted behavior

Comment: Sure, it was exactly what the OP asked for: *"how do I recursively remove **files of a specific extension**?"*. So please remove the down-vote...